# Lexical scoping in a SELECT list?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Consider the following query:

```
SELECT dgc.Id, h.[identity], h.associate_number, h.pos_start, h.pos_stop,
    ISNULL((
        SELECT DATEADD(DAY, -1, ih.pos_start)
        FROM #hr_data_dgc ih
        WHERE ih.associate_number = h.associate_number AND
            ih.Id = (dgc.Id - 1)
    ), h.pos_stop) AS new_pos_stop
FROM #hr_data h
    JOIN #hr_data_dgc dgc ON dgc.[identity] = h.[identity]
```

and take specific note to the `ISNULL` statement that is being leveraged against the result from the sub query for the `new_pos_stop` field. This works as expected if the sub query returns `NULL`.

Now, if I were to change that query slightly:

```
SELECT dgc.Id, h.[identity], h.associate_number, h.pos_start, h.pos_stop,
    (
        SELECT ISNULL(DATEADD(DAY, -1, ih.pos_start), h.pos_stop)
        FROM #hr_data_dgc ih
        WHERE ih.associate_number = h.associate_number AND
            ih.Id = (dgc.Id - 1)
    ) AS new_pos_stop
FROM #hr_data h
    JOIN #hr_data_dgc dgc ON dgc.[identity] = h.[identity]
```

it will return `NULL` for `new_pos_stop` instead of grabbing the value from `h.pos_stop` in the sub query.

Here is what I don't understand. I'm able to leverage the value of `h` and `ih` (i.e. the current row being selected) in the `WHERE` clause but not in the `SELECT` list?

In short, it **appears** that the `SELECT` list does not have lexical scoping (loosely using that term), am I correct on that? In other words, the `SELECT` list can **only** leverage stuff in the *direct* `FROM` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is simple:

`ISNULL()` can only be utilised if query at level `ISNULL()` is used returns any results.
In both examples external query returns rows with `Id and associate_number` you use in correlated subquery.

In first example `ISNULL()` is at external query level. Therefore for each external query row for which subquery doesn't return results (or they are `NULL`) 2nd param of `ISNULL()` is placed instead.

In second one, `ISNULL()` is at subquery level, therefore if there is no row fulfilling subquery `WHERE` conditions, the column value in external query will be `NULL` meaning no rows were returned by subquery. Please note, that if there existed subquery row fulfilling `WHERE` conditions with `ih.pos_start == NULL`, `ISNULL()` would work as you intended.

Hope the explanation is understandable :)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a scoping issue.  The queries are working exactly as they should.  Consider the first version:

```
isnull((select DATEADD(DAY, -1, ih.pos_start). . ), h.pos_stop) AS new_pos_stop
```

There are *two* ways the subquery can return `NULL`.  The first is when `ih.pos_start` is `NULL`.  The second is when the subquery returns no rows at all.  In the context of a scalar subquery, no rows is treated as `NULL`.

In both these cases, the values will be substituted with `h.pos_stop`.

Now consider the second case:

```
(select isnull(. . ., h.pos_stop) . . .) as new_pos_stop
```

The `isnull()` is *inside* the subquery.  So, this only handles the first case above.

You are getting `NULL` values because the subquery is not returning any rows.